# C# - ReportViewer - make class not static

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

I have a class DependencyReportViewer that is correspond for creation a ReportViewer control in my program. This class works perfectly. In XAML we define only this line for each report that we wants:

```
  <ctr:DependencyReportViewer EmbeddedReportName="Program.View.Reports.ReportName.rdlc" ReportData="{Binding ReportData}"/>
```

First part of the class:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Class="Program.View.Controls.DependencyReportViewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        IsVisibleChanged="WindowsFormsHost_IsVisibleChanged">
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And the worst part of the class:

```
public partial class DependencyReportViewer : WindowsFormsHost
{
    private static ReportViewer ReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    private static int ReportIsRunning = 0;

    static DependencyReportViewer()
    {
        DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

        try
        {
            RenderingExtensions = ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            RenderingExtensions = new RenderingExtension[0];
        }

        ReportViewer.ReportError += ReportViewer_ReportError;
    }


    public static RenderingExtension[] RenderingExtensions { get; private set; }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ReportDoneEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ReportDone", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(DependencyReportViewer));
    public event RoutedEventHandler ReportDone
    {
        add { AddHandler(ReportDoneEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ReportDoneEvent, value); }
    }

    public string EmbeddedReportName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EmbeddedReportNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmbeddedReportNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmbeddedReportNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EmbeddedReportName",
        typeof(string), typeof(DependencyReportViewer));

    public Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>> ReportData
    {
        get { return (Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>>)GetValue(ReportDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReportDataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReportDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ReportData",
        typeof(Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>>), typeof(DependencyReportViewer),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ReportData_Changed));


    private static void ReportData_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sts = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref ReportIsRunning, 1, 0);
        if (sts != 0)
            return;

        var rv = (DependencyReportViewer)d;
        var data = (Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>>)e.NewValue;

        RenderingCompleteEventHandler evt = null;
        evt = (sender, rea) =>
        {
            ReportViewer.RenderingComplete -= evt;
            sts = Interlocked.Exchange(ref ReportIsRunning, 0);
            if (sts == 1)
                rv.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ReportDoneEvent));
        };
        ReportViewer.RenderingComplete += evt;

        DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.Reset();
        DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = null;
        if (data != null)
        {
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted));

            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = rv.EmbeddedReportName;

            var l = new List<ReportParameter>();
            foreach (var item in data.Item2)
            {
                l.Add(new ReportParameter(item.Item1, item.Item2));
            }
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(l);

            foreach (var item in data.Item1)
            {
                var rds = new ReportDataSource(item.Item1);
                rds.Value = item.Item2;
                DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            }
        }
        DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }

    private static void ReportViewer_ReportError(object sender, ReportErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref ReportIsRunning, 0);
    }


    public DependencyReportViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WindowsFormsHost_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            this.Child = DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer;
        }
        else
        {
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.Reset();
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = null;
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
            this.Child = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code works normally only in situations, when we have only one UserControl with this ReportViewer opened. If we open two or more controls, then the last open control will take over ReportViewer. In other words it is possible to open only one ReportViewer at the same time.

Now I want to have a possibility to open multiple controls with multiple report viewers. As I get the problem is that this class is static. And when we define a new control, then in "this.Child = DependencyReportViewer.ReportViewer;" line we just reset this viewer to the newest control.

But the man who wrote this had a skill much greater then I have now. I failed multiple times to set this class nonstatic with XamlParseException. How can I convert this class to nonstatic?

Comment: Another option to consider is the [Syncfusion Report Viewer](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-viewer). It is a WPF control and a free community version is available.